# How to search for multiple elements in Ruby array using regexp

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex, search

Given:

```
my_array = ['america', 'bombay', 'bostwana', 'cameroon']
```

I can locate the index of the first element that, say, begins with `'bo'` with

```
my_array.find_index { |l| l.start_with? 'bo' }
```

How can I locate all such elements?

Comment: Your last comment on @davidhu2000's now-deleted answer ("I'm in need of votes, so if you think it deserves it, kindly upvote the question.") is akin to "I need an "A", so please give me one if you think I deserve it". Don't beg, it's unbecoming.

Comment: If you just want the elements and not their indexes then then `my_array.grep(/^bo/)` will suffice.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the elements:

```
my_array.find { |element| element.start_with? 'bo' }   # => "bombay"
my_array.select { |element| element.start_with? 'bo' } # => ["bombay", "bostwana"]
```

---

If you want the indices:

```
my_array.index { |element| element.start_with? 'bo' } # => 1
my_array.map.with_index.select { |element, _| element.start_with? 'bo' }.map(&:last)
  # => [1, 2]
```

Comment: Thanks, ndn. Gosh, that (all-indices return implementation)  looks scary! :)

May I request you to upvote my question if you think it deserves to be? Total noob here (in case you didn't realize). Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map.with_index` with a conditional and `compact` the result.

```
my_array.map.with_index{ |element, index| index if element.start_with? 'bo' }.compact
```

---

### How this works

**map**

[`map`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map) will take all of the values and "map" them to the value that is returned when each item is passed into the given block.

```
my_array.map { |element| element.start_with? 'bo' }
# => [false, true, true, false]
```

**with_index**

To get the index values you can use [`with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) like this:

```
my_array.map.with_index { |element, index| index }
# => [0, 1, 2, 3]

my_array.map.with_index { |element, index| index if element.start_with? 'bo' }
# => [nil, 1, 2, nil]
```

**compact**

Then, to get rid of the `nil` values you can call [`compact`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-compact) on the returned array.

```
my_array.map.with_index{ |element, index| index if element.start_with? 'bo' }.compact
# => [1, 2]
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much for the step-by-step, Scott. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
['america', 'bombay', 'bostwana', 'cameroon']
  .each_with_index # to get indices
  .grep(->(e) { e.first.start_with? "bo" }) # I ❤ Enumerable#grep
  .map(&:last) # get indices
#⇒ [1, 2]
```

I posted this to show the approach that is rarely used. [`Enumerable#grep`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep) accepts anything, that is used to select items basing on triple-equal case comparison.

Passing `Proc` instance there is cool, because `Proc` has a default [`Proc#===`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Proc.html#method-i-3D-3D-3D) implementation: it’s simply being invoked on receiver.

Answer (score 0):

In the interest of readability, I would use the following:

```
my_array.each_index.select {|idx| my_array[idx].start_with?("bo") }
```

Comment: 1. it requires temporary local variable, 2. it performs redundant secondary lookup on each iteration, 3. there are in fact 3 methods.

Comment: @mudasobwa, I count 4, n'est-ce pas?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I counted dots. `Array#[]` was scolded in the previous item :)

Comment: The operative word you've both missed is "chain." I'd rather do a "redundant" lookup once per iteration than iterate over the data twice. Regardless: readability.

Comment: Since readability, while important, isn't the only important factor, and because I can never resist once I start wondering, I benchmarked the answers: https://gist.github.com/jrunning/da9e9e3c00bda19c7d213ceebb38de90